# JPA / Hibernate entity response missing one column

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, kotlin

This is my entity:

```
@Table(name = "user")
data class User (
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
val id: Long = 0L,

@get: NotBlank
val e_mail: String = "",

@get: NotBlank
val password: String = "",

@get: NotBlank
val name: String = "",

@get: NotBlank
val surname: String = "",

val mail_confirm: Int = 0,

val time_of_registration: Timestamp = Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()),

@Column(name = "admin")
val is_admin: Int = 0
)
```

I have a GET method which does the following:

```
return userRepository.findById(userID).map { user ->
        ResponseEntity.ok(user)
    }.orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build())
```

But when I hit the url I get a response without 'is_admin' field. I added 'System.out.println(user.is_admin) to the GET method and it prints the value from database but it never returns it in the json result.

Comment: In the JSON you get, the `is_admin` field is missing? Or only its value?

Comment: The field is missing

Comment: Try this one: val admin:Int=0 and remove the @Column

Comment: I forgot to say, that was my first try, also didn't work...